# How to Removing App from Multitask Bar in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, task

I am able to remove app with help of onBackPressed() method. 
I am doing it by below method:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onBackPressed();
  Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
  startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
  startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  startActivity(startMain);
  QuestionListActivity.this.finish();
 }
```

But the app has still instance in multitask bar of cell/tab.
I want to remove it. Please suggest..

Comment: What do you mean by multitask bar?

Comment: multitask bar is a button, any android have 3 mainly button home, backpress and rest one is multitask

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want your app to appear in the list of recent apps (long press home button), add this to your `Activity`declaration in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

Comment: This solution does not work on Android L anymore. Any suggestion?